# How can I use $(this) reference inside another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a case like this -

```
$('<first-selector>').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('<second-selector>').click(function(){
           /* Here I want to use the top $(this) reference to do some business. 
              I don't want to use like var thisObj = $(this) and refer it inside          
              the click function*/
        });
    });
});
```

How to use `$(this)` reference inside another object?

Comment: Why don't you want to save `$(this)` before you enter the second callback?

Comment: @ChristopherArmstrong That is what I don't want to do. I mentioned the same in the comment.

Comment: You've already identified the only (sensible) solution.  The system variable 'this' automatically gets replaced to reflect the current scope, so to refer to it from within a different scope you'd have to cache it manually in a different variable.

Comment: The only way to perform such functionality is with `var thisObj = $(this)`.  Why are you adverse to using such a solution?

Comment: Why are you using `each` at all - just `.click` would have been enough?

Comment: @Bergi Not only `.click()`, there are few other methods I'm calling on this group of objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('p').click($.proxy(function(){
           console.log($(this)); // returns <div>
           /* Here I want to use the top $(this) reference to do some business. 
              I don't want to use like var thisObj = $(this) and refer it inside          
              the click function*/
        }, this));
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TRw4X/

Comment: So, in this case we cannot get the reference to `P` objects. Right?

Comment: There is only one `this` keyword. You can keep the default behavior and have it point to `p`s, or tweak it and have it point to `div`s, but you can't do both. The only way to keep two references to distinct objects is to have two variables...

Comment: I was going through http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/ API but couldn't get it's use. Can you explain this method's significance in brief?

Comment: @Sriram: You might want to read about the [native method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use the $(this) from the first function within the second function and refer to it as $(this)? That's not possible since jQuery maintains the this-context. You have to run with something like this:

```
$('<first-selector>').each(function()
{
    var first = $(this);

    first.click(function()
    {
        $('<second-selector>').click(function()
        {
            var second = $(this);
            // do something with first and second.
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer was already offered twice then deleted because the OP does not want it for some unknown reason.

Comment: This is the way to go though. I always like to add a `$` prefix to any jQuery object variables to distinguish them. `var $first = $(this);` but that is personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the best solution (because you SHOULD reference it through a variable like the other solutions suggest)... you can always use the parent() method if the second-selector is a child of the first.

```
$('<first-selector>').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('<second-selector>').click(function(){
          /*$(this) is now referencing <second-selector> and by adding parent() it will go up the elements until it find the requested selector*/
          $(this).parents('<first-selector>').doSomething();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think *firstselector* is a parent of *secondselector*

Comment: You might be right... but I'll leave the answer just in case it is.

Comment: @ComputerArts #Bergi is right. It is not parent of second selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass reference of the object in jQuery event.

```
$('<first-selector>').each(function(){
    $(this).click($(this),function(){
        $('<second-selector>').click(function(e){
           var $elem = e.data.
           /* Here I want to use the top $(this) reference to do some business. 
              I don't want to use like var thisObj = $(this) and refer it inside          
              the click function*/
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "solve" your question is to not use jQuery.

Yet you tag your question with jQuery.

What exactly do you want to do here and why is the easy (and a common javascript idiom of using a closure) dismissed by you?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do this without jQuery, too

Comment: @Bergi -- of course you could, you create a handler that creates the context you want -- just like jQuery does.  You could have it be the parent in the handler, nothing stops you.

Comment: No, native `addEventListener` also uses the DOM element as the context - no difference to jQuery. And creating a custom context using `.bind()` would work in jQuery as well, just as the dereferencing variable the OP doesn't want

Comment: Sure non-jQuery works "with" jQuery.  My point is that a solution using `.bind()` is not a jQuery solution.  Feel free to take to me to task on technicalities but I think it is a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

In this case on DOM ready all the first-selector are bind with click event handler. On clicking first-selector, second-selector is bind to the click event. To use the $(this) which reperesent first-selector you have to write the code as

```
$('<first-selector>').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    var oldthis = $(this);
    $('<second-selector>').click(function(){
       alert(oldthis.val());
    });
});
```

});

make sure first-selector tag is not same as second-selector tag.
try this in form

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).click(function(){
            var oldthis = jQuery(this);
            jQuery('input.hello').click(function(){
                alert(oldthis.val());
            });
        });
    });
});
```

First click input text field. It will alert value of input TEXT field when button with hello class is clicked.